# Onmouseover grab the title attr. and replace the original content with it, reset onmouseout

Tags: jquery

If a span has a title and the mouse is over it, then hide the originalcontent and replace it with the intitlecontent. But onmouseout give back and show the originalcontent again. The first part of the script works well, but how to hide the revealed intitlecontent and get back the originalcontent?

```
<span title="intitlecontent">originalcontent</span>

  $('span[title]').hover (
    function() {
      $(this).text (function() {return $(this).attr('title');})
    },
    function() {
      $(this). ???;
    }
  );
```

Comment: @SLaks cool. Now that's going to be useful :)

Comment: @PeeHaa: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the original content in `$.data`:

```
$('span[title]').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).data('text', $(this).text())
               .text($(this).attr('title'));
    },
    function() {
        $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
    }
);
```

Comment: A small mistake was there, the 3. line is: $(this).data('text', $(this).text())

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span[title]').hover (
  function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.data("orgText", elem.text() );
    elem.text(elem.prop('title'));
  },
  function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.text(elem.data("orgText"));
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, too. Stackoverflow rules!